# dealing with real numbers in Integer Vector Homomorphic Encryption lib

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am using Integer Vector Homomorphic Encryption for the encryption lib.

I have to multiply a learning rate of 0.01 (i.e. between 0 and 1) by the encrypted data (vector) but it is not integer. I had wanted to multiply by 1/10 instead. Is it possible? because it is know that HE scheme doesn't support division. Is the any way out?

Comment: What is the name of the scheme you are using? Would you have some link to that lib?

Comment: As the question is currently written, it’s more about “using a specific library” (which is rather off-topic here) than it is about cryptography as defined in [our help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help). You might want to edit your question to make it a bit more on-topic… removing the reference to the library and reformulating your question in a more general way (meaning: asking about “Homomorphic Encryption for Integer Vectors” instead of the “Integer Vector Homomorphic Encryption lib”) should void the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways...

If the message space of your scheme is $\mathbb{Z}_t$, then you can

1. Multiply all the plaintexts by $10^k$ before encrypting them and instead of multiply those vectors by a learning rating between $0$ and $1$, multiply them by an *integer* learning rate between $0$ and $10^k$.
2. Remove the divisions and track the changes introduced by this remotion. For instance, instead of evaluate $x = \frac{c_0 + c_1}{10}$, do $y = c_0 + c_1$ and keep in mind that $y = 10x$ so you can find the right answer after decrypting. Take a look to the section 3.2 (Division-Free Integer Algorithms for Classification) of this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=179548)...

But if the message space of the scheme you are using is (let's say) more robust, like a polynomial ring, then you can encode double values into plaintexts, which enables you to encode the learning rate, then encrypt it and finally multiply by the vector of ciphertexts.

[That answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32627/how-can-we-define-division-operation-by-using-fully-homomorphic-encryption/32641#32641) may be helpful to you.